# How do proponents of the 'Critical Text' respond to the claim that it preserves an anti-Trinitarian corruption dating from the fifth century?

Tags: church-history, new-testament, textual-criticism

When [Dr Vance Smith](http://textus-receptus.com/wiki/George_Vance_Smith), a Unitarian, was appointed to the Committee to revise the Authorised Version, public opinion objected to the appointment and [Drs Westcott and Hort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westcott_and_Hort) (Hort, also, leaning towards Unitarianism) said that if Dr Smith was not allowed then neither would they be involved in the revision.

All three were permitted to contribute to the revision and during that revision Drs Westcott and Hort approached other members of the committee, singly, seeking to influence them in regard to the Greek text being translated - the Received Text, also called the *Textus Receptus*.

The ensuing revision resulted in the imposition of a new Greek text (that of Drs Westcott and Hort) in 1881, something not envisaged by the purpose of the revision. Many objected to this, among them [Dean John Burgon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Burgon) who, in his book ‘*Revision Revised*’, pointed out that between the two manuscripts upon which the W&H text strongly depended, Codex Aleph (*Sinaiticus*) and Codex B (*Vaticanus*), there was disagreement in over three thousand places *in just the four gospels*.

[Hermon Hoskier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_C._Hoskier), in his book ‘*Codex B and its Allies*’ demonstrated that there had been a recension (a supposed ‘reversion’ to the original) in the fifth century, based on Egyptian and Coptic influence, resulting in a corrupted text.

The *correction* of this recension, of the fifth century, resulted in the [Received Text](https://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear).

Hermon Hoskier further demonstrated that the two manuscripts upon which Drs Westcott and Hort so much relied were, in fact, *proof of the corrupt recension*. The reason they survived, say Dean John Burgon and Hermon Hoskier, is that they were recognised for their fault and were little used, just retained as reference.

The resulting Greek text of Westcott and Hort can be seen to be weakened, compared to the Received Text, in many places where the Deity of Christ and where the relationship of Father and Son are in view. (See below for just a few of those places.)

Overall, about 9,000 alterations, additions and deletions were made to the Received Text (see [Dr Scrivener’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Henry_Ambrose_Scrivener) comparative text of 1881) amounting to about 7% of the text. And it is noticeable to anyone who studies these changes in detail that there is a definite bias appearing in regard to the deliberate favouring of Codices Aleph and B on these particular occasions.

What is the response of those who favour the so-called ‘Critical Text’ above the Received Text to the overall changes in emphasis seen in these texts - the bias evidently towards Unitarianism ?

---

A full explanation of the following texts and the effect of changing them is [available here](https://faithsaves.net/texts-deity-christ-attacked-modern-bible-versions-corruptions-greek-critical-text-defense-received-text-readings/). (See [the PDF version](https://faithsaves.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Places-where-the-Deity-of-Christ-is-removed-from-modern-Bible-versions.pdf) for a much better display of the Greek letters.)

- ... and they **worshipped him** ...  Luke 24:52
- ... the **only begotten Son** ... John 1:18
- ... the Son of man, **which is in heaven** ... John 3:13
- ... purchased **with his own blood** ... Acts 20:28
- ... Christ came, **who is over all, God blessed for ever** ... Romans 9:5
- ... neither let us tempt **Christ** ... 1 Corinthians 10:9
- ... singing to the **Lord** ... Colossians 3:16
- ... **God** was manifest in flesh ... 1 Timothy 3:16
- ... the dead ... stand **before God** ... Revelation 20:12

---

Note (edit)

I have used the word 'bias' in its second meaning as listed by the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=bias&_searchBtn=Search) - 'to exert an influence unduly'. This is exactly, precisely, a description (as demonstrated in detail by Herman Hoskier in '*Codex B and its Allies*' and Dean John Burgon in his book '*Revision Revised'*) of placing undue preponderance on just two manuscripts against the vast weight of evidence contained in over 5,000 other Uncials and miniscules, the Patristic Citations, the Versions and the Lectionary quotations. It results in a bias introduced in the fifth century and reproduced in the Critical Text as the above examples clearly indicate.

Comment: I found the following "LONG" article by Wallace and he address this issue at length. He also addresses Westcot and Hort. https://www.bereanpatriot.com/majority-text-vs-critical-text-vs-textus-receptus-textual-criticism-101/  It's really detailed but relatively easy to understand. I did not read the whole thing but I hope it helps as it relates to your question. Lastly, and this is a question I have? Your thread states for "Unitarians," yet Biblical Unitarians believe the Bible is the only source of truth where Unitarian Universalists deny the Bible is the source of truth, just saying!

Comment: @Mr.Bond The article to which you refer states (towards the end) that it is 'personal opinion' : and indeed it is. It does not cover the depth that it is expressed by such devoted, lifelong experts as Dean John Burgon and Herman Hoskier. I did not find an answer to the question in that article, I am afraid. (Though I did read it, as you suggested.)

Comment: I have just finished reading the entire article from the link given by Mr. Bond. What it says about Westcott and Hort is interesting, especially since they stuck to the "older is better" rule on textual criticism. Because of this their N.T. relied heavily upon Codex Vaticanus and Codex Sinaiticus. Yet in the last ~140 years since the Westcott & Hort 1881 Critical Text, papyri from the 300s, 200s, and even a few from the 100s have been discovered. Despite this, the Critical Text of the New Testament remains virtually unchanged from ~140 years ago. Hort said the Textus Receptus "was vile".

Answer (score 1):

There are many scholars who advocate for the Critical Text and reject the claim that it preserves an anti-Trinitarian corruption:

- Bruce Metzger - Metzger was a prominent New Testament scholar and
  textual critic who was involved in the production of several major
  editions of the Greek New Testament. He argued that the evidence for
  the anti-Trinitarian corruption is weak and that the Critical Text is
  the most reliable representation of the original text.
- Bart Ehrman - Ehrman is a well-known New Testament scholar and author
  who has written extensively on textual criticism. He has argued that
  the evidence for the anti-Trinitarian corruption is unconvincing and
  that the Critical Text is the most accurate representation of the
  original text.
- Daniel Wallace - Wallace is a professor of New Testament Studies at
  Dallas Theological Seminary and a leading authority on textual
  criticism. He has written extensively on the topic and has argued
  that the Critical Text is the most reliable representation of the
  original text.
- Michael Holmes - Holmes is a textual scholar who has worked on
  several major editions of the Greek New Testament, including the SBL
  Greek New Testament. He has argued that the charge of
  anti-Trinitarianism is unfounded and that the Critical Text is the
  most reliable representation of the original text.

---

According to proponents of the Critical Text, the claim that it preserves an anti-Trinitarian corruption is based on a misinterpretation of the evidence. The textual variants in question are relatively minor and do not have any bearing on the doctrine of the Trinity. In addition, the textual variants are not unique to the Critical Text but are found in other manuscript traditions as well.  The specific textual variants that have been cited as potentially anti-Trinitarian by some scholars are primarily found in certain manuscripts of the New Testament and include passages such as 1 John 5:7-8 and John 1:18:

- 1 John 5:7-8 is a disputed passage that reads, *For there are three
  that bear witness in heaven: the Father, the Word, and the Holy
  Spirit; and these three are one. And there are three that bear
  witness on earth: the Spirit, the water, and the blood; and these
  three agree as one* (ὅτι τρεῖς εἰσιν οἱ μαρτυροῦντες, τὸ Πνεῦμα καὶ τὸ ὕδωρ καὶ τὸ αἷμα, καὶ οἱ τρεῖς εἰς τὸ ἕν εἰσιν). This passage is absent from the majority of
  Greek manuscripts but is found in some later manuscripts such as the Codex Montfortianus and in
  Latin manuscripts such as the Codex Monacensis and the Codex Ottobonianus.
- John 1:18 is another disputed passage that reads, *No one has seen
  God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the
  Father, He has declared Him* (Θεὸν οὐδεὶς ἑώρακεν πώποτε· μονογενὴς υἱός, ὁ ὢν εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρὸς, ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο). Some manuscripts, including the Codex
  Sinaiticus, read "God only begotten" (μονογενὴς θεὸς) instead of "only begotten Son" (μονογενὴς υἱός)
  which has led some scholars to suggest that this reading is
  anti-Trinitarian.

However, it's important to note that the overwhelming majority of textual variants in the New Testament are minor and do not have any significant impact on Christian doctrine. While some scholars may interpret these textual variants as evidence of anti-Trinitarianism, others argue that they do not undermine the core teachings of the Christian faith.

Furthermore, proponents of the Critical Text argue that the charge of anti-Trinitarianism is historically unfounded. The doctrine of the Trinity was well established by the fifth century and there is no evidence to suggest that the scribes who produced the variant readings had any intention of altering the doctrine.

Comment: This skirts the subject and makes claims but without hard reference, without direct quotes of authorities 'He has argued ; He has argued ; He has written extensively.' But where is the direct quote ? This is hearsay, not _evidence_ of the actual argument put forth with a substantial foundation.  Nor is there any textual evidence presented, only - yet again - assertions  _but without the direct evidence_.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself seems to make some unwarranted assumptions.  As a non-Trinitarian, I *support* the Received Text (Textus Receptus) and/or the Majority Text.  There is no need to think that the revised versions, as meddled with by Westcott and Hort and others, are either more accurate, or necessary to a proper understanding of God the Father and the Son of God.

Jesus taught that the Father was in him.  He did not, however, teach that he *was* the Father.  None of the passages touching on the deity of Christ say that it was Christ himself who was God--and, as far as I know, this holds true regardless of the manuscript in question.  Many seem to think that "son of God" is the same as "God."  But this is neither true in English, nor in Greek.  The reference to John 1:18 is an interesting case in point--the alteration is that which changed "son" to "God" such that the ESV, for example, has translated it as "No one has ever seen God; the only God, who is at the Father's side, he has made him known."  This is a ridiculous translation, and contradicts the rest of the book of John which identifies the Father as God.  If "the only God" is "at the Father's side," then, obviously, the Father *cannot* be God.  Therefore, the *corruption* is easy to identify, because it is a corruption which will introduce a contradiction.

The word "son" has a meaning, and the expression changes in its significance if this word is dropped.  If the full expression were "the son of the Father," dropping "Father," and saying just "the son," would change its meaning very little, but dropping "son," and saying just "the Father," would change it completely.

```
The son of the Father = the Son
The son of the Father ≠ the Father
```

The changes made in the modern revisions with reference to Christ, his lordship, and his identity, are both unnecessary and specious.  It is these changes which constitute a corruption of the text, and not the other way around.  Nothing is "preserved" in the critical text, but rather it is destroyed.

The Catholic church, never one to be shy about its accomplishments, publishes quite openly regarding the changes it made to the Biblical manuscripts.  The work of editing those manuscripts was documented during the late nineteenth century / early twentieth century<sup>1</sup>.

### Catholic Revisions

Here is what [they say](https://www.catholic.com/encyclopedia/new-testament) about these manuscripts.

> (2) Ancient Versions
>
> **Several are derived from original texts prior to the most ancient Greek MSS.** These versions are, following the order of their age,
> Latin, Syriac, Egyptian, Armenian, Ethiopian, Gothic, and Georgian.
> The first three, especially the Latin and the Syriac, are of the
> greatest importance. (I) Latin version.—Up to about the end of the
> fourth century, it was diffused in the West (Pro-consular Africa,
> Rome, Northern Italy, and especially at Milan, in Gaul, and in Spain)
> in slightly different forms. The best known of these is that of St.
> Augustine called the “Itala”, the sources of which go as far back as
> the second century. **In 383 St. Jerome revised** the Italic type
> after the Greek MSS., the best of which did not differ much from the
> text represented by the Vaticanus and the Sinaiticus. **It was this
> revision, altered here and there by readings from the primitive Latin
> version and a few other more recent variants, that prevailed in the
> west from the sixth century under the name of Vulgate.** (2) Syriac
> Version.—Three primitive types are represented by the Diatessaron of
> Tatian (second cent.), the palimpsest of Sinai, called the Lewis codex
> from the name of the lady who found it (third cent., perhaps from the
> end of the second), and the Codex of Cureton (third cent.). The Syriac
> Version of this primitive epoch that still survives contains only the
> Gospels. **Later, in the fifth century, it was revised after the Greek
> text.** The most widespread of these revisions, which became almost
> the official version, is called the Pesitta (Peshitto, simple,
> vulgate); the others are called Philoxenian (sixth cent.), Heraclean
> (seventh cent.), and Syro-Palestinian (sixth cent.). (3) Egyptian
> Version.—The best-known type is that called Bohairic (used in the
> Delta from Alexandria to Memphis) and **also Coptic from the generic
> name Copt, which is a corruption of the Greek aiguptos Egyptian.** It
> is the version of Lower Egypt and dates from the fifth century. A
> greater interest is attached to the version of Upper Egypt, called the
> Sahidic, or Theban, which is **a work of the third century, perhaps
> even of the second.** Unfortunately it is only incompletely known as
> yet.
>
> **These ancient versions will be considered precise and firm witnesses of the Greek text of the first three centuries only when we have
> critical editions of them; for they themselves are represented by
> copies that differ from one another. The work has been undertaken and
> is already fairly advanced.** The primitive Latin version had been
> already reconstituted by the Benedictine D. Sabatier (“Bibliorum
> Sacrorum latinm versiones antiquae seu Vetus Italica”, Reims, 1743, 3
> vols.); **the work has been taken up again and completed in the
> English collection “Old-Latin Biblical Texts” (1883-1911),** still in
> course of publication. **The critical edition of the Latin Vulgate
> published at Oxford by the Anglicans Wordsworth and White, from 1889
> to 1905, gives the Gospels and the Acts. In 1907 the Benedictines
> received from Pius X the commission to prepare a critical edition of
> the Latin Bible of St. Jerome (Old and New Testament).** The
> “Diatessaron” of Tatian is known to us by the Arabic version edited in
> 1888 by Msgr. Ciasca, and by the Armenian version of a commentary of
> St. Ephraem (which is founded on the Syriac of Tatian) translated into
> Latin, in 1876, by the Mechitarists Auchar and Moesinger. The recent
> publications of H. Von Soden have contributed to make the work of
> Tatian better known. Mrs. A. S. Lewis has just published a comparative
> edition of the Syriac palimpsest of Sinai (1910); this had been
> already done by F. C. Burkitt for the Cureton codex, in 1904. There
> exists also a critical edition of the Peshitto by G. H. Gwilliam
> (1901). As regards the Egyptian versions of the Gospels, the recent
> edition of G. Horner (1901-1911, 5 vols.) has put them at the
> disposition of all those who read Coptic and Sahidic. The English
> translation, that accompanies them, is meant for a wider circle of
> readers.

Notice how, strangely, the Catholic encyclopedia considers these other-language manuscripts to be more "original" than "the most ancient Greek MSS"?  This was because the Latin, etc. were in their own hands and were edited/altered by them, as they document in the record.  Notice how many times they reference a "revision" and speak of the work of correcting and revising these texts.

When they say "The work has been undertaken and is already fairly advanced," they refer, of course, to a work that is now completed, as this encyclopedic entry is about a century old.  They were documenting what was taking place in the late nineteenth century and early twentieth century.  It was during about this time that Westcott and Hort did their work.  It is interesting that the Catholic record does not mention their names, nor does it record who was doing the work they referenced.

### Clues from the Dead Sea Scrolls

Dr. Bill Barrick, a Hebrew professor who has served as a consultant to nine Bible-translation projects, explains that the scribes who copied the Biblical manuscripts regarded them as so sacred that even when they had made copying errors, and were forced to reject the flawed manuscript, they would not burn it, nor destroy it.  Because it contained portions of the sacred scripture, they still handled it carefully.  They placed these manuscripts in earthen jars, and gave them an honorable burial.  The Dead Sea Scrolls, found in Qumran, are these flawed manuscripts.  We know they are incomplete because the Jews considered the name of God to be so sacred that a separate scribe would write it, and there are many blanks in the manuscripts where the name was not yet added.

The Dead Sea Scrolls are considered to be as much as 1000 years older than the Masoretic texts used to translate most Bibles today (certainly any Bible pre-dating their discovery in about 1947).  They were well preserved in their earthen vessels within those desert caves.

The fact that these manuscripts have many flaws, and yet *appear older*, is of considerable interest in the discussion of which manuscripts are actually superior: those appearing "more ancient," or those which appear newer, likely because they were worn out from being copied and were replaced.  The ones chosen to be used, and copied, would certainly be the ones deemed superior by the scribes, who had very strict policies with the work of copying.  Errors were not tolerated.  Even if a "typo" had crept into the text, it was forbidden to correct it--the scribes would make a marginal note to indicate if they had observed another version of the manuscript to have had a different spelling, but they would not make any change to the manuscript being copied.  In many cases, those other manuscripts referenced have not survived, and these marginal notes are all we have to help us understand the possible changes as well as the strict culture among the scribes of preserving the text exactly.

### Conclusion

A careful review of the manuscripts will show that in most cases the "anti-Trinitarian" versions are actually the most reliable.  The "corruptions" are those of the "critical text" line, and this line is well-known for its origination in Egypt.  The *codex siniaiticus, codex vaticanus,* and *codex alexandrinus*, the three dominant minority texts used in the modern translations, are all part of the "critical text" which Westcott and Hort promoted following their edits.

---

<sup>1</sup> A footnote on the Catholic encyclopedia website says: "Catholic Answers is pleased to provide this unabridged entry from the original Catholic Encyclopedia, published between 1907 and 1912."

Comment: I would have expected which addressed my question, namely, the matter of the Coptic Recension and its subsequent effect, which requires revision. It is the Coptic Recension which alters the emphasis of scripture.

Comment: " He did not, however, teach that he was the Father." The trinitarian claim is exactly that the Son is not the Father and great care is taken in claiming it.  If you understand that trinitarianism teaches that the Son is the Father then you do not understand trinity doctrine.

Comment: @MikeBorden Because I explain something that follows from the text does not mean I am opposing the Trinity per se.  There are many views out there, and my intent is simply to explain what the Bible says.  Since the Bible says that the Father is "the only true God," if Jesus is _not_ the Father, then he cannot be God either.  As you admit that Jesus is not the Father, you have a difficult time establishing your three Gods (God the Father, God the Son, God the Holy Spirit).  The Bible says the Father is the only true God, so the other two are either the Father or are not God.

Comment: Do you think ""the Father" is God's name?  Jesus' controversial claim is that "God is his own personal, private, particular Father" (John 5:18 - The adjective ιδιος (idios) means one's own or private as opposed to public, or peculiar as opposed to normal or general.)  God is not Jesus' Father  in the same general sense as He is ours, by dint of creation.  Common sense tells us that what is begotten is equal in nature to what begets.  The Bible is clear that the Jews understood this perfectly and wanted to stone Him for blasphemy.

Comment: @MikeBorden "Father" is not a name. Even children know this. But the Father is God. And according to Jesus, the Father is "the only true God."  That should settle the matter, if common sense were at all common.  "God the Father" (a biblical term) being "the only true God" (the words of Jesus) means that "God the Son" (a non-biblical term) can only be a _false_ God.  The fact is, people have created a god of their own cherished opinions--an ideological idol--that then undermines the whole concept of the atonement.  But it would take more than comment space to lay out the reason for this.

Comment: So you believe that John 5:18 records the Jewish misunderstanding of what Jesus said.

Comment: @MikeBorden In effect, yes.  But it's not all what you might think.  The authority with which Jesus spoke (he was speaking the Father's words, as he emphasized multiple times) was different than the way the Jewish teachers spoke. It was common among the Jews to call themselves a "son of God." When Jesus did this, it should have been nothing out of the ordinary, yet they were impressed that his statement was more meaningful than theirs. (Look up "bar mitzvah", which means "son of the law", and you may discover that the Jews also would call their sons "a son of God" after their 12th year.)

Comment: Bar Mitzvah began in the middle ages.  There was no such custom during Jesus' day.  This verse is not the words of the Jews but the Apostle John's inspired take on what the Jews believed Jesus meant.  John gives no indication that the Jews got it wrong and John himself couldn't have gotten it wrong.

Comment: @MikeBorden I am not asserting anything with regard to the history of Bar Mitzvah itself, but that Jews would begin to call their sons "a son of God" when they had completed their twelfth year was a custom during Jesus' time.  This is a part of why the Jews were demonstrating a spirit of hypocrisy in calling out Jesus for his own use of the expression.  It may be that their feigned aversion to Jesus' saying it gave impetus to an evolution in their custom toward the Bar Mitzvah in later times.  But that is just speculation.  Their own use of "son of God" is not mere speculation.

Comment: @MikeBorden. [CLICK HERE](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13912-son-of-god) for one explanation of the Jewish usage of "son of God."

Comment: It seems pretty clear that Jesus' claim to be the son of God, or that God was his Father, is distinct from the sonship of, say, Adam.  The clarity comes from just what the link you provided describes.  A normal claim of sonship would never have enraged the Jews as it did but, as it stands, they accused Jesus of blasphemy which is not a reaction that the term (as you understand it) would ever provoke.  The claim Jesus made was understood by them as a claim of equality with God and that does not indicate a common usage of "son of God".  My Father worketh hitherto, and I work.

Comment: @MikeBorden "Which was the son of Enos, which was the son of Seth, which was the son of **Adam, which was the son of God.**" (Luke 3:38, KJV)

Comment: Exactly.  This kind of usage would not have enraged the Jews or been foreign to them in any way.  Jesus was claiming something else.

Comment: The words were not different.  The expression "the son of God" was identical.

Comment: If it was common usage they wouldn't have thought he was claiming equality with God.